# How can I access x:Name from Code Behind?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in which I am using DataGridTemplateColumn and DataGridTextColumn.
I want to access these columns at runtime so I have assigned x:Name property to them.
But I was not getting that value in code behind, so I looked for DataGrid and then read objects by iterating through DataGrid.Columns. How can I read x:Name property from that object in C#?

I need this to perform some specific operations with particular columns at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datagrid column does not get added to the visual tree. (so maybe you cant access it in the code behind because of this) - see vinces [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx) on the visual layout.

You can look at the header property, or you could derive and add your own property to uniquely identify the column. That's what I do, I've found the columns a bit vanilla and have derived a fair few for different uses.

Comment: But if you did have them reading the x:Name in code is not easy, see [How to access x:Name-property in code - for non FrameworkElement objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7172430/575530)

Comment: Once you start walking the visual tree you get in trouble, add reflection to that and it can get messy fast.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to define an attached property:

1) Derive a new class from DataGrid with the attached property

```
Public Class FilteringDataGrid
   Inherits DataGrid


   Public Shared Function GetFilterProp(ByVal element As DependencyObject) As String
      If element Is Nothing Then
         Throw New ArgumentNullException("element")
      End If

      Return CStr(element.GetValue(FilterPropProperty))
   End Function

   Public Shared Sub SetFilterProp(ByVal element As DependencyObject, ByVal value As String)
      If element Is Nothing Then
         Throw New ArgumentNullException("element")
      End If

      element.SetValue(FilterPropProperty, value)
   End Sub

   Public Shared ReadOnly FilterPropProperty As  _
                          DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilterProp", _
                          GetType(String), GetType(FilteringDataGrid), _
                          New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
End Class
```

2) Set the prop in Xaml

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn local:FilteringDataGrid.FilterProp="ItemName" x:Name="dbcItemName" Header="Item" >
```

3) Read the value

Comment: That is very nice solution, and not so obvious somehow