# Finding the x:Name in Xaml from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

From getting a little help, I managed to make the window only open once, now I want to change the window to a page. When I do this obviously `.Show();` and also `.Close();` have no extension method.

Now I added a frame to my Generic page (As this will be on all forms):

```
<Frame x:Name="FrameNavigate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="1296,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

And I put the `x:Name"FrameNavigate"` in the XAML. In the code behind the Generic page, I wanted to add this piece of code to open the page up on the frame.

```
private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (help != null)
    {
        help.Close();
        help = null;
    }
    else
    {
        help = new xamlHelp();
        FrameNavigate.Navigate(new xamlHelp());
    }
}
```

But It says that `FrameNavigate` doesn't exist?

EDIT:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Canvas Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3DDF2" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                        <Button x:Name="btnHelp" Content="Help" Click="btnHelp_Click" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" Margin="110,10,0,0" Height="30" Width="70" Style="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
                        <GridSplitter Height="30" Width="1" Margin="95,10,0,0" Background="Gray"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnSettings" Content="Settings" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,0,0" Click="btnSettings_Click" Height="30" Width="70" Style="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Width="350" Height="850" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                        <Frame x:Name="FrameNavigate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="1296,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate> 
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

I have this code which has got no errors, but when you click the button nothing appears?

```
Master master = ((Button)sender).TemplatedParent as Master;
Frame frame = (Frame)master.Template.FindName("FrameNavigate",master);
frame.Navigate(new xamlHelp());
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for the page (XAML and Code Behind) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access x:Name-property in code - for non FrameworkElement objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172030/how-to-access-xname-property-in-code-for-non-frameworkelement-objects)

Comment: Both Page and Frame are framework elements? How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @MarioStoilov It is not a duplicate, I've looked at that code already and it didn't work.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Yeah sure Ill add to a edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Since `Frame` exists in `ControlTemplate`, you can't access it directly like this from code behind.**

Ask template to get that for you by using [FrameworkTemplate.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Also you need to get `Master` control (*obviously to get template of Master control*) which you can get via `accessing TemplatedParent of sender button`.

This is how you need to do it:

```
Master master = ((Button)sender).TemplatedParent as Master;
Frame frame = (Frame)master.Template.FindName("FrameNavigate", master);
frame.Navigate(new xamlHelp());
```

Comment: I understand, where you have added `btn1` I thought do you mean my button? If so, It errors.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check. It should be instance of Master control instead.

Comment: that bit of the code still errors when I added Master, says that it is a type but used like a variable.

Comment: I have casted the second line `(Frame)` and no errors, but when i click the button no page appears :/

Comment: That's entirely different question the one you posted above (unable to find control in code behind). Please raise separate question for this with relevant code.

Comment: Its not really a different question, because it may run the code but if the page isn't showing it may not be able to find the page.

Comment: @Ben - Question says - `Finding the x:Name in Xaml from C#` which you are able to do right now. And not able to find the page? You are creating new instance of page `xamlHelp()`. There is issue somewhere in your code which can't be help until you post a small sample to replicate your issue here.

Comment: Ok, well i am going to work through it with the help that has been given. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

The Navigate(TypeName) method takes a Type object!

```
Frame frame = (Frame)this.FindName("FrameNavigate");
frame.Navigate(typeof(xamlHelp)); //frame.Navigate(help);
```

Have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate.aspx

and at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771188.aspx

ps. Note you are not using your `help` variable in you else code block.

Comment: You should not need to do this

Comment: @FredrikRedin `Object instance not set to a object` on the line `frame.Navigate(help);` Any ideas?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I agree with you, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Ben perhaps a property within xamlHelp() is not instantiated?