# How can I write Xaml(LayoutTransform) in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a XAML code (`LayoutTransform`) that I can not write in code behind. How to do this? I need to write in code behind because I'm using a virtual `Grid`. This is the XAML code:

```
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just assign `ScaleTransform` to `Grid`'s `LayoutTransform` property like this:

```
grid.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform();
grid.UpdateLayout();
```

**UPDATE**

This is updated code:

```
var nameScope = NameScope.GetNameScope(MyRootElement);
var scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
nameScope.RegisterName("st", scaleTransform);

var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
transformGroup.Children.Add(scaleTransform);
TestGrid.LayoutTransform = transformGroup;
```

`MyRootElement` is the Name of your root element (`Window`, `Page`, `UserControl`). And you shouldn't call `UpdateLayout` after setting `LayoutTransform` property, because this property has metadata property `AffectsMeasure=true`, so changing transform will set `Grid`'s property `IsMeasureValid` to False, and that will force layout update.

Comment: Ok, but I need to set x:Name.

Comment: @FernandoFragoso if you need `x:Name` you can create separate variable `ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();` and then assign it to `LayoutTransform` property of `Grid`

Comment: @melya And how to set x:Name in the variable? Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoFragoso here it is described [How to access x:Name-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172030/how-to-access-xname-property-in-code-for-non-frameworkelement-objects)

Comment: Answer from previous comment doesn't describe, how to set x:Name attribute, only how to get it. I update my answer.